# injector inside an angular2 decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been writing a custom method decorator in typescript for Angular2.

The decorator needs to have access to the 'ApplicationRef'.

Is it possible to inject into method decorators? If not, how else can i access the applicationRef?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing injector instance for use in components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409328/storing-injector-instance-for-use-in-components)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing much research it doesn't seem that this is possible.