# Angular10: AutoInject Dependancy for extended Component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

- **Auto Inject `HttpClient` to extended class `HttpHelper` without injecting in base class `LoginService`**

I've many services which are having HTTP API calls. I have created a common HTTP Class that instantiates httpClient and some other helper variables and functions that services can directly use without repetitive instantiation.

**login.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService extends HttpHelper{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private userManagementService: UserManagementService) {
    super(this.http);
  }

  login(data: IAuthPayload): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/users/login', data, this.getHttpOptions({
      auth: false
    }))
      .pipe(
        map((res: ILoginResponse) => {
          AuthService.setToken(res.data.token);
          this.userManagementService.setUserData(res.data.user);
          this.authService.setAuthState({ is_logged_in: true });
        })
      );
  }

}
```

**http.helper.ts**

```
export class HttpHelper {
  protected apiUrl = '';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.apiUrl = ENVIRONMENT.API_ENDPOINT;
  }

  protected getHttpOptions(options?: CustomHttpHeaderOptions) {
    // function Definition
  }
  
  // Many More members here 
}
```

- `LoginService` extends the `HttpHelper` and `httpClient` instantiation must be in the `HttpHelper` and not in any service. e.g. `LoginService`.
- is that possible if we just extend the `HttpHelper` and not inject `httpClient` into the `LoginService`. `httpClient` should auto inject in `httpHelper` and we will use `httpClient` in `LoginService` without injecting it into service and use directly `httpHelper` `httpClient` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can easily create your injectable class with Angular Injector:

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Allows for retrieving singletons using `AppInjector.get(MyService)` (whereas
 * `ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(MyService)` would create a new instance
 * of the service).
 */
export let AppInjector: Injector;

/**
 * Helper to set the exported {@link AppInjector}, needed as ES6 modules export
 * immutable bindings (see http://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html) for 
 * which trying to make changes after using `import {AppInjector}` would throw:
 * "TS2539: Cannot assign to 'AppInjector' because it is not a variable".
 */
export function setAppInjector(injector: Injector) {
    if (AppInjector) {
        // Should not happen
        console.error('Programming error: AppInjector was already set');
    }
    else {
        AppInjector = injector;
    }
}
```

And Use it this way:

```
import {AppInjector} from './app-injector';
const myService = AppInjector.get(MyService);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43695820/2126355)