# How can I use the Angular AppInjector solution in a Karma test?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, integration-testing, karma-runner

Using the top-rated answer for this question:

[Storing injector instance for use in components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409328/storing-injector-instance-for-use-in-components)

I have a class with a constructor, which also has service dependencies that are injected as follows:

```
protected constructor(private settings: MosaicSettings, private imageData: ImageParseData) {
   this.Elements = AppInjector.get(ElementsService);
   ...
}
```

This works fine for the app:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    setAppInjector(injector);
  }
}
```

but within a Karma test, AppInjector is undefined:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

I've tried everything I can think of to make this work in the test suite, including manually setting TestBed providers and calling setAppInjector() with a newly created Injector. There doesn't seem to be an answer anywhere with regard to testing.