# Angular 2 Dependency injection outside from constructor for instantiation

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Every tutorial about DI in Angular 2 is to set the dependencies into the constructor. But what if I want to create an instance of the class and the class have some dependencies to other classes.

I have class A and B. Class B should be inject into A. But A is different every time and should be able to create a instance of it.

If I set up the DI in the constructor from `A`, how to call `new A()` ?

I tried to add `B` as private variable to `A` with the `@Inject(B)` decoration.

```
class A {
  @Inject(B) b: B;
}
```

Comment: If you're using DI, you *don't* call `new A()`; the point of it is you don't need to resolve the dependencies and create the instance yourself.

Comment: But A should be every time different, so I have to create a new instance of.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say.

Comment: A have foo as member. But foo is not the same. So I want to create instance of A, that I can set foo. If A provide by DI, foo will be everytime the same.

Comment: I don't see foo in your example. Please provide a specific demonstration of what you're trying to do, and why.

Comment: I dont understand what you dont understand. I have two classes A and B. A should be able to create single instances but should have use B as DI. Like B is a Singleton and I use in A `B.getInstance()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Inject Dependency outside Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101865/angular-2-inject-dependency-outside-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

Angular dependency injection only supports constructor injection.

You can inject an injector

```
constructor(private injector:Injector) {}

foo() {
  var x = injector.get(B);
  var a = new A(b);
}
```

This might also help in your case where DI injects a factory function that returns a new instance every time it's called.
[Create new instance of class that has dependencies, not understanding factory provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472103/angular-2-dependency-injection-create-new-instance-of-class-that-has-dependencie/38473200#38473200)

You can also set up new injectors, also one that include parent injectors for finding providers. See also [Getting dependency from Injector manually inside a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536409/getting-dependency-from-injector-manually-inside-a-directive/40537194#40537194)

Comment: thanks for the fast response. The both ways behind the links looks a bit ugly - more like "damn we need a workaround".

I idea was to build a HTTP-Builder where I can build my request url and then only call request() on the builder which use http.get(....)

Comment: No idea why you find them ugly. I find them both quite straight forward.

Comment: In the example above, you can also inject `B` into the constructor instead of the `Injector`. Subsequent calls to `injector.get(B)` will return the same instance (just in case this is unclear).

Comment: I find the DI in constructors particularly bad with SubClasses that need to DI and `super(the_DI_item)` if the super class needs them.  If you just DI `Injector` and pass to the super then it removes the need to constantly update all constructors.  Thanks.

Comment: But IMHO it makes the code harder to reason about. I don't need to update contructors often, but I'm using Dart and here inheritance for components didn't land ye ;-).