# Angular 2/4/5/6 Model Logic

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection

So this is a pretty abstract example, but let's take the following model & service definitions:

**Model/Object definition - car.ts**

```
... /*imports*/
export class Car{
    color: string;
    wheels: number;
    oilChangeDate: Date;
    tyreChangeDate: Date;

... /*Additional properties*/

}
```

**Service - car.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CarService{
    currentCar: Car;

    constructor(http: Http){
    ... /*Initialization*/
    }

    ...

    serviceCurrentVehicle(){
        currentCar.oilChangeDate = new Date();
        currentCar.tyreChangeDate = new Date();
        /* Some http request */
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. Is it against Angular 2/4 style/design guides to move the logic behind *serviceCurrentVehicle* to the model definition? Why?
2. Is it against Angular 2/4 style/design guides in general to have logic attached to the model definitions? And if not, how does one access a service while maintaining the constructor of the object? (i.e. without dependency injection)

I have looked at posts similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39101865/3951987) prior to creating this question.

EDIT:
Came across [this post on OAuth](https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-series-part-2-domain-models-and-dependency-injection/) earlier too which is the kind of thing I'm aiming to create, but (a) the tutorial doesn't include the code for calling the HTTP request when saving a User and (b) I can't find any supporting references to this kind of domain model w/ business logic in the official documentation/style guides.

Cheers

EDIT 2:
So it's over a year since I created this, but there still isn't any decent resources I've come across for this. I implemented a model definition in our system, and I'm looking for ways to improve it at the moment since it's enterprise level.

Comment: I'd still like some opinions on this - especially since I've posted it - as there have been numerous changes to Angular