# How to extend a service in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am migrating my app from Angular 3 to Angular 7,

Ionic 3 to Ionic 4

There are two services `BaseHttpService` which is mainly responsible for Http calls and `AppService` which extends the `BaseHttpService` to make calls.

In the migration [Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration), it is mentioned to use `{ providedIn: "root" }` in services.

But the base and parent class in services is nowhere mentioned.I tried many approaches but didnt went through.

I have a parent service which has some dependencies like

```
export abstract class BaseHttpService implements OnInit {

   private baseUrl: string = Constants.BASEURL;
   protected method: string;
   protected serviceUrl: string;
   protected headers: Headers;
   constructor(private http:) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
   }
}
```

and I want to extend the service

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AppService extends BaseHttpService{
  constructor(private _http: Http, ) {
    super(_http);
}
```

But it is throwing error while running on browser

Comment: (private http:) without type !!

Comment: what's the exception ?

Comment: Please check this example link: may be this is helpfull for you.
[how to extend service with dependencies in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50308933/3012323)

Comment: @GhoulAhmed it's the repeated parameter property, *not* the type, that's part of the problem; the *access modifier* is the but that needs removing.

Comment: This is for Angular 7 not 2. I am migrating to Angular 7

Comment: And has that materially changed since Angular 2? Are you saying there's a problem with that solution now and, if so, what?

Comment: The problem was with the debugging limitation of Angular Application on Firefox . The problem with the code was Http Module wasnt injected in the main module, which i was not able to diagnose on firefox console.

Answer (score -3):

base Http Service:

```
export abstract class BaseHttpService implements OnInit {

   private baseUrl: string = Constants.BASEURL;
   protected method: string;
   protected serviceUrl: string;
   protected headers: Headers;
   constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
   }
}
```

App Service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AppService extends BaseHttpService{
  constructor(private _http: Http, private baseHttpService: BaseHttpService ) {
    super(_http, baseHttpService);
}
```

Comment: you send two params  constructor(private _http: Http, private baseHttpService: BaseHttpService )   but define one param in parent constructor

Comment: yes, because parent class params have to be repeated in child class.

Comment: But one of the child class's params now is an instance of the class it extends? How does that make sense?

Comment: abstract class cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @manishkumar answer to this question you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038791/inheritance-and-dependency-injection solution is to use injector for dependencies and then super this injector for class that is extended by super class, sorry for wrong answer