# angular 2 Can't resolve all parameters for parent class

Tags: javascript, angular

I can't seem to find why it would do this.  I have a base class that most of my class inherit from.

```
import { Http, HttpModule, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';

export class ServiceBase {
 constructor(private http:Http){}
}
```

I have a child class, if I just call `super()`, I get an error that my parameters does matched, after much research, it appears that I have to pass `http` into Super base the parent class has it. Hence, create `http:Http` and pass it to super and I get the following error.

> "can't resolve parameters".

How do I resolve this?

```
import { Http, HttpModule, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';

export class childService extends ServiceBase {
   constructor(private http:Http){
       super(http) // Can't resolve all parameters for parent class
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance and dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038791/inheritance-and-dependency-injection)

Comment: You'd need to make those Services `Injectable` to inject `Http`